# Microsoft Azure Face API - Face detect return values, but not return faceId

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

Microsoft Azure Face API - Face detect  return object

```json
{
    "faceRectangle": {
      "top": 114,
      "left": 206,
      "width": 167,
      "height": 167
    }
}
```

but I need faceId. It not return faceId. I did not fount solution about it.

[image]

Comment: Show your RESTful API endpoint, full POST request with input parameters.

Comment: https://ibb.co/DC70LMc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

If you need to get the face Id of the image, you can use the below request.

In the request, you need to add **`returnFaceId =true`** to get the face Id.

```
Post https://your-azure-faceapi-endpoint.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId =true
 { "url": "{Image Url here}" }
 Header:
 Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key : "your-api-key"
```

**Postman:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Face - Detect With Url - REST API (Azure Cognitive Services - Face) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/faceapi/face/detect-with-url?tabs=HTTP#detect-with-url-example)

Comment: Thanks!
But the same response is returned. 
Without 'faceId'

Comment: @Ang Try with another image URL.

Comment: I tried, It didn't help.

Comment: Can you share your snip and how you are trying?

Comment: Screenshot- https://ibb.co/DC70LMc

Comment: I tried with the same URL of the image in Postman it returned with faceid https://i.imgur.com/k1Wv7hS.png , https://i.imgur.com/E8mHwz9.png , 
 https://i.imgur.com/WJ3CuKX.png

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't return? I'm on a free account, could it be because of that?

Comment: Yep, Check this Document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-face-detection#face-id it has limitations.